# Unable to restore nuget packages with "WARNING: Invalid parameter" error

Tags: jenkins, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget

I'm trying to build a Xamarin Android project at my build server (Mac OS X) but I'm unable to restore some of nuget packages (3 or 22). These three packages can be downloaded but for some reason couldn't be copied to the workspace.

I cleaned the workspace, removed nuget cache - same result.

> Restoring NuGet package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm.29.0.0.1.
>   Restoring NuGet package modernhttpclient.2.4.2. Restoring NuGet
>   package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics.29.0.0.1. Adding package
>   'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics.29.0.0.1' to folder
>   '/Volumes/Storage/Jenkins/jobs/Build1/workspace/packages'
>   Adding package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm.29.0.0.1' to folder
>   '/Volumes/Storage/Jenkins/jobs/Build1/workspace/packages'
>   Adding package 'modernhttpclient.2.4.2' to folder
>   '/Volumes/Storage/Jenkins/jobs/Build1/workspace/packages'
>   WARNING: Invalid parameter WARNING: Invalid parameter WARNING: Invalid
>   parameter

Comment: Without the full exception callstack it is difficult to know what the problem is. Can you run the nuget restore with the extra `-Verbosity detailed` arguments? I have seen the invalid parameter when restoring with nuget 3 when the timestamps in the .nupkg are in the future but this is a guess. NuGet v2 works OK in this case.

Comment: Hi Alexey, are you using packages from another source other than nuget.org?

Comment: my verbosity parameter was rejected by nuget as unknown, probably I used it improperly, I'll give it another try: `nuget restore -verbosity detailed` @MattWard and get back to you on this.

Comment: @RuiJarimba no, only nuget.org. I'm using it on Mac though. When I open the same solution in Xamarin Studio - it restores all the packages as required. So the issue is in restore in terminal using `nuget restore myproject.sln` command

Comment: Xamarin Studio is not affected by this problem. What version of NuGet are you using?

Comment: The latest and greatest: `3.4.3`

Comment: I just reverified, works fine, probably was some file locks or similar. Anyway, Verbosity detailed would help me if I use it properly from the very start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a restart and packages folder cleanup it started to work fine. Just use `-Verbosity detailed` command to get more insights on an issue:

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference

Take into account that the `install`, `update` and `restore` commands has different way to define verbose level of output.

Comment: Same thing here, strange, rebooted and fixed.

Comment: Indeed, reboot made it. Cleaning package caches didn't help alone